# Recursion in abstract class - Python

Tags: python, recursion, abstract-class

Tag.py

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Tag(ABC):
    def print(self, tag):
        print("<" + self.name, end="")
        for key, value in self.attributes.items():
            print(" " + key + "=\"" + value + "\" " ,end="")
        print(">")
        for child in self.children:
            self.print(child)
        print("</" + self.name + ">")
```

CompositeTag.py

```
from Tag import Tag

class CompositeTag(Tag):

    def __init__(self, name, attributes, children):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.children = children

    def print(self):
        super(CompositeTag, self).print(self)


child = CompositeTag("test", {}, [])
ct = CompositeTag("test", {}, [child,])
ct.print()
```

When I'm executing this code I get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CompositeTag.py", line 25,
>   in 
>       ct.print()   File "CompositeTag.py", line 20, in print
>       super(CompositeTag, self).print(self)   File "Tag.py", line 26, in print
>       self.print(child) TypeError: print() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How can I call recursively method print in abstract class?

Comment: `self.print(self, child)` should only take `child` as an argument. No need to pass `self`.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with recursion, you are simply using `super` incorrectly (and would fail even if recursion weren't there).

Comment: Why are you using `abc` at all with no abstract methods?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - can You tell me more? I think that print method in CompositeTag class uses its parent method (Tag class) and passes itself. And in print method I would like to use print method recursively (method from Tag class)
 `child in self.children:
            self.print(child)`

Comment: @JordanSinger Sorry. My mistake. I placed wrong code (I was trying many things and I placed wrong version of my code). Of course there should be only child param. And the error is from the code with only one param - child. –

Comment: @user2357112 - This is only one method from class. In original - full class there are abstract methods. But I think it is not important for that question.